# How to get code coverage for Compose UI tests?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I'm now somewhat familiar with UI testing within Jetpack Compose thanks to the extensive [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing), but I can't make Android Studio to run Compose tests with coverage. We are currently using Jacoco as coverage tool to generate the reports, but according to this [Github issue](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1208) it does not look like coverage for Compose is a priority for the team (sadly :S).

As we don't want to keep UI tests aside when evaluating code coverage, is there any way to enable code coverage in Android Studio for Compose tests, either using Android Studio or an external tool/library?

Comment: Have you anything for coverage?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet

Comment: From latest updates in that [GItHub Issue](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1208) seems like there'll be some reconsideration. Fingers crossed it'll get picked up soon!